# How does docker-compose start container on login (ubuntu/systemd)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose, systemd

I run multiple services in multiple containers referenced in 2 docker-compose.yml files.

```
/srv/
|
+-- docker-openvpn-data/
|   |
|   +-- docker-compose.yml
|
+-- docker-svenv.nl-data/
    |
    +-- docker-compose.yml
```

These docker-compose.yml file are started (`docker-compose up`) on deployment.

When my host reboots (unattended upgrades) my machine doesn't start the containers again, *when I ssh into the box to start them manually all containers are instantly started.*

My host runs Ubuntu 16.04 which uses systemd.

- What configuration takes care of the containers starting on SSH login?
- Can I *alter* this configuration to start at boot?

Comment: If it actually works like this, it's non-standard.   Ask your hosting provider.

Comment: I believe it's possible to put user-level systemd stuff in place. Do you have anything in `~/.config/systemd/`?

Comment: No there is not, I had an overwrite in /etc/systemd/system/docker.d/docker.conf but I tested booting without it which made no difference...

Comment: Ask question in stackoverflow or unix.stackexchange. This forum is mainly for devs, not ops.

Answer (score 0):

The docker daemon will respect the settings for reboot policy when the daemon starts, so if you set your containers to `restart: always` in your docker-compose.yml they will start at boot (when the docker daemon starts). (See first section of this page: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/host_integration/)

Of course this does require the docker daemon to run and it looks like that only starts when you login. This probably means that the docker daemon service is set-up to start on your own user session. You can use linger to make Ubuntu spawn a user session on boot, causing the user specific systemd service, like Docker, to start.

The command for this is `loginctl enable-linger username`.

From the man pages:

```
enable-linger [USER...], disable-linger [USER...]
    Enable/disable user lingering for one or more users. 
    If enabled for a specific user, a user manager is spawned
    for the user at boot and kept around after logouts. 
    This allows users who are not logged in to run long-running 
    services. Takes one or more user names or numeric UIDs 
    as argument. If no argument is specified, enables/disables 
    lingering for the user of the session of the caller.
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/loginctl.1.html

Comment: Just tested again, the containers/dockerd don't start until a login has been made. I suspect some kind of systemd file doing this?

Comment: It sounds like the systemd docker service is running under your user instead of being system wide. By default this means that the service will only run after you login. Depending on the OS you might be able to use something like `loginctl enable-linger username` to make sure the systemd processes get started right away after boot. Obviously this won't work if your system doesn't use loginctl, but other login services might have the same option.

Comment: Thanks for the information, can I debug this and determine username?

Comment: The systemd and dockerd process run as root, I also log in as root (yeah I know, private key though). I tried `loginctl enable-linger root` but no luck...

Comment: Then it has to be something else and I'm not really sure how to help you. Maybe you can ask on serverfault? It doesn't really seem docker related anymore to me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help but put the following in your docker-compose.yml file:

https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart

What happens is when you have this in your compose file it starts the docker containers on boot.  Not sure this is relevant to your problem or not as its not a systemd setting but a docker setting.

Hope it helps though and it fixes your problem if it does.

Comment: Please remember links are volatile, write down the answer so if in the future the link disappears your answer remains useful.